# NSDocument/NSWindow: How to programmatically open the "save/move" popup?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

When clicking on the title of a document window, the default behavior is to show a popup allowing to rename/move the document.

I'm implementing a custom titlebar and would like to replicate this behavior. How can I programmatically show this popup when the user clicks on my custom titlebar?

Here's an example of the popup in TextEdit:

[image: Example]

Comment: Just FMI: Why do you implement a custom title bar?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad My app only allows one document to be open at a time. I replaced the title text field with a pop up button that lets the user switch between documents. I want to show the system move/rename dialog when the user clicks on my custom title bar.